# Turning camera off in fine-uploader on iOS

Tags: ios, fine-uploader

I'm very new to fine-uploader; I hope my question is relevant...

I'm trying to disable the camera for users of our Web App on iPad and iPhone only (iOS), both for Safari and Chrome. I have tried setting the option `camera: {ios: false}` but the camera option still shows in Safari and Chrome. When I use `workarounds: { ios8BrowserCrash: true}`, the camera option does disappear in Chrome but still shows in Safari. What am I missing?

We are using `fine-uploader 5.1.2`, I briefly tried `5.2.2` with the same results. The app is `HTML5`, `Javascript`, `Angular` with `Java` back-end. I have tested on iPad with `iOS 8.3`, `8.4` and `9 beta`.

As an aside, the reason I'm trying to disable the camera is due to iOS often crashing when loading the image from the camera. I have found the application crashing a lot less when loading from the device image library, bypassing the camera. Is that a known issue with iPad/iPhones?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: If the `multiple` attribute is _not_ present on the file input element, you will have access to the iOS camera. So, I would expect that there is some setting that is resulting in Fine Uploader leaving this attribute off of the file input that it creates and wraps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Ray. For reference, I'm now using the latest `FineUploader version 5.3.0`. 
As you suggested the multiple attribute was being removed. I traced it to the `input.removeAttribute("multiple");` code below (s3.fine-uploader.js):

```
setMultiple: function(isMultiple, optInput) {
    var input = optInput || this.getInput();

    // Temporary workaround for bug in in iOS8 UIWebView that causes the browser to crash
    // before the file chooser appears if the file input doesn't contain a multiple attribute.
    // See #1283.
    if (options.ios8BrowserCrashWorkaround && qq.ios8() && (qq.iosChrome() || qq.iosSafariWebView())) {
        input.setAttribute("multiple", "");
    }

    else {
        if (isMultiple) {
            input.setAttribute("multiple", "");
        }
        else {
            input.removeAttribute("multiple");
        }
    }
},
```

Despite `options.ios8BrowserCrashWorkaround` being set to true in my code (`ios8BrowserCrash: true`), the program was still going through to `removeAttribute("multiple")` line of code when running on IPad/Safari.
After several tries and errors I found out that (possibly...) the library code was missing testing for the condition `qq.iosSafari()`on an iPad (iOS 8.3) ; the `qq.iosSafariWebView()`  test isn't sufficient to detect the Safari browser on my iPad, therefore missing the code where the multiple attribute is set. 
I found out that the following options values in my calling code fixed the issue.

```
function initialiseS3() {
    uploader = new qq.s3.FineUploader({
      element: $element[0],
      template: $(contents)[0],
      debug: false,
// iosEmptyVideos workaround must be false to enable FineUploader to keep multiple:true in iOS
      workarounds: {
                     iosEmptyVideos: false,
                     ios8BrowserCrash: true
                   },
// Must add the test qq.iosSafari() to set multiple to true and have the camera turned off on iPad
      multiple: qq.ios8() && (qq.iosSafari() || qq.iosChrome() || qq.iosSafariWebView()) ? true : false,
      camera: {
                ios: false
              },
… (more initialisations)
`
```

The last catch was to override the default value for the workaround option `iosEmptyVideos` and set it to `iosEmptyVideos: false` to avoid the library forcing `multiple` to false again. I hope this makes sense…

Comment: The `qq.iosSafariWebView()` function seems to work as expected. It is only to return `true` if the page is running inside of `WebView`. The "normal" Safari mobile browser is not expected to result in a `true` return value here. We _do not_ want to apply this workaround to "normal" Safari. So, the code in Fine Uploader appears to be working correctly. Whatever issue you are having is probably due to some problem with your configuration.